# Why don't my desktop icons stay in place?

Tags: gnome, icons

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and a few days ago I switched to gnome3. Now I have still a few folders I'm using for everyday work on my desktop. I want to group them in specific areas of the desktop to reflect my working style ... but every time I log out and in again, all folders, icons etc. are grouped at the left border of the screen.

Is there some way to stop this (meaning: keep the icons in the places where I put them)? I tried the "keep aligned" switch in the desktop right-klick menu, but this didn't change anything. It only helped to align icons on a virtual grid. Then I did web searches in google and olso specifically in "ask ubuntu" but to no avail. The only question I found (April 2011) was unanswered.

Update: The question I'm referring to is one of several dealing with icons that end up being stacked one over the other. I didn't see any thread dealing with *this* problem.

Comment: Which question is it? If it's unanswered please don't ask it again, all that does is fragment the information.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, could it be _related_ to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98318/organize-desktop-by-name-sometimes-doesnt-retain-order-after-a-restart) question and this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/886667)

Comment: I would say "file a bug report" - however upstream will probably say "we dont support the use of nautilus desktop" - remember the gnome-devs have this option switched off by default in gnome-tweak-tool (clean desk policy and all of that).